# Can't get my css selector to work properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

the last `:checked` call in my css code is not working. I want to be ably to have the `.nav-bar-element`'s move from off the screen to where they are now when the hamburger icon is clicked, but I can't seem to get the selector working.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
 body {
  background-image: url(http://www.hayesandjarvis.co.uk/medias/sys_master/hcf/hbb/8912480731166.jpg);
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.75;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  font: 400 15px/1.8"Raleway", sans-serif;
  color: #777;
}
.nav-bar {
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 64px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.nav-bar:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease, width 0.3s ease;
  transition: 0.4s ease, width 0.3s ease;
}
.nav-content {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  float: right;
  height: 64px;
  width: 512px;
  color: #000;
}
.nav-content .nav-bar-element {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 16px 25px 16px 25px;
}
.nav-content .nav-bar-element a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#nav-button {
  display: none;
}
.menu-button {
  z-index: 101;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: absolute;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  top: 8px;
  right: 25px;
}
.bar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 66%;
  background-color: #000;
  left: 20%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease, width 0.3s ease;
  transition: 0.4s ease, width 0.3s ease;
}
.bar:nth-child(1) {
  top: 24%;
}
.bar:nth-child(2) {
  top: 47%;
}
.bar:nth-child(3) {
  top: 47%;
}
.bar:nth-child(4) {
  top: 71%;
}
#nav-button:checked+ .menu-button .bar:nth-child(1) {
  width: 0px;
}
#nav-button:checked+ .menu-button .bar:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#nav-button:checked+ .menu-button .bar:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#nav-button:checked+ .menu-button .bar:nth-child(4) {
  width: 0px;
}
#nav-button:checked+ #change-me {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="bgimg-1">
  <!--<div class="nav-bar-bg"></div>-->
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-button" />
    <label for="nav-button" class="menu-button">
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </label>

    <div class="nav-content" id="change-me">
      <div class="nav-bar-element"><a href="#projects"><i class="fa fa-rocket" aria-hidden="true"></i> Projects</a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-bar-element"><a href="#about-me"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> About Me</a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-bar-element"><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-inbox" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the `+` because the last one is a child not a sibling

Comment: Thanks @zer00ne I did that, but the style color didn't change and checking the dev tools the styles from that block are still not being applied. Is there something else that I am missing?

Comment: Sorry use ~, my bad

Comment: Try it now, normally the last 2 solutions would work but there's a class that has a strong selectivity and the actual target is `#click-me`'s children,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need glasses it is a sibling, **but** not the adjacent sibling, so use `~` instead of `+`

OR

Use `+` between checkbox and label and a `+` between label and `#change-me`,

<del>Remove the `+` on last ruleset, because `#change-me` is a child of `#nav-button`, not na sibling.</del>

OK I finally got enough specificity! Use this:

> ```
>   #nav-button:checked ~ .nav-content#change-me * {
>       color: #fff;
>     }
> ```

**SNIPPET**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
 body {
  background-image: url(http://www.hayesandjarvis.co.uk/medias/sys_master/hcf/hbb/8912480731166.jpg);
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.75;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  font: 400 15px/1.8"Raleway", sans-serif;
  color: #777;
}
.nav-bar {
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 64px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.nav-bar:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease, width 0.3s ease;
  transition: 0.4s ease, width 0.3s ease;
}
.nav-content {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  float: right;
  height: 64px;
  width: 512px;
  color: #000;
}
.nav-content .nav-bar-element {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 16px 25px 16px 25px;
}
.nav-content .nav-bar-element a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#nav-button {
  display: none;
}
.menu-button {
  z-index: 101;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  position: absolute;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  top: 8px;
  right: 25px;
}
.bar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 66%;
  background-color: #000;
  left: 20%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease, width 0.3s ease;
  transition: 0.4s ease, width 0.3s ease;
}
.bar:nth-child(1) {
  top: 24%;
}
.bar:nth-child(2) {
  top: 47%;
}
.bar:nth-child(3) {
  top: 47%;
}
.bar:nth-child(4) {
  top: 71%;
}
#nav-button:checked+ .menu-button .bar:nth-child(1) {
  width: 0px;
}
#nav-button:checked+ .menu-button .bar:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#nav-button:checked+ .menu-button .bar:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#nav-button:checked+ .menu-button .bar:nth-child(4) {
  width: 0px;
}
#nav-button:checked ~ .nav-content#change-me * {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Sam Erickson</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="bgimg-1">
    <!--<div class="nav-bar-bg"></div>-->
    <div class="nav-bar">
      <input type="checkbox" id="nav-button" />
      <label for="nav-button" class="menu-button">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </label>

      <div class="nav-content" id="change-me">
        <div class="nav-bar-element"><a href="#projects"><i class="fa fa-rocket" aria-hidden="true"></i> Projects</a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-bar-element"><a href="#about-me"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> About Me</a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-bar-element"><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-inbox" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The color of the text still doesn't change

Comment: @Sam ok I got it that was tricky, check it out,. That looks pretty cool, BTW.

Comment: Awesome @zer00ne you are a life saver! And thanks! I've been working pretty hard at it! Do you mind walking me through your solution? You used both the class and id, does it need to be that specific? And what is the * at the end?

Comment: You are very welcome sir. The `*` is an everything selector. In this case it is targeting all descendants of `#change-me`. You can narrow that down to `.fa` which is your true target. I coupled `.nav-content` and `#change-me` because the specificity for `.nav-content` and `nav-bar-element` was overriding `#change-me` white with black. In retrospect that combination is not necessary because `#change-me` falls too short of the real objective which are the Font-Awesome icons (`.fa`), So try this: `#nav-button` + `.menu-button` + `#change-me` `.fa` `{color: #fff;}`